# Laravel attribute accessor capital letter is ignored

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, accessor, lumen

I am using `Lumen` framework. I have one problem, I need to set custom accessor for attribute, but the problem is that column in database starts with capital letter.
For example `Logo`.And in case of first capital letter, accessor is not called while retrieving object, I have tried with several columns, columns with name starts from small letter works perfectly.

```
 public function getLogoAttribute($value)
```

This accessor doesn't work ,because name of column is `Logo`
I cannot change the name of columns in the database, but need to use accessors in my application.
I understand that I can change sources of `Eloquent` framework, but maybe there any other way to get it working.
Thanks.

Comment: How did you implement the accessor method?

Comment: It doesn't matter, I am implementing it wit the same way using column name which start from lowercase letter and it works.

Comment: Keep the accessor as it is and try `$model->{'Logo'}`, I had to do this once for a column name containing a dash.

Comment: I have already tried this, it shows content of this field without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spent several hours trying to find answer surfing the net, but than decided to find this part in code by myself.
I have found it.

It is located in `vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model`
Method     `public function attributesToArray()`

Modify the part of this method like this

```
 $mutatedAttributes = $this->getMutatedAttributes();

        // We want to spin through all the mutated attributes for this model and call
        // the mutator for the attribute. We cache off every mutated attributes so
        // we don't have to constantly check on attributes that actually change.
        foreach ($mutatedAttributes as $key) {
            if (! array_key_exists($key, $attributes) ) {
                if(array_key_exists(ucfirst($key), $attributes)) {
                    $key = ucfirst($key);
                }
                else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
```

If you have several capital letters in column name this will not work.

This bad solution for this problem, just name you database columns according to convention and you won't have any problems ( I have ability to change column name in my case).

**UPDATE**

You can also modify class like this

```
    /**
     * Indicates if the model mutated attributes can have different case from ex. User_comments instead of user_comments.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $upperCaseMutatedAttributes = false;

 if($this->upperCaseMutatedAttributes && array_key_exists(ucfirst($key), $attributes)) {
                    $key = ucfirst($key);
                }
```

You can override this variable in your class.

Comment: I guess you should accept your answer until we have a better way to solve the problem. Also, I think it's important to cross-reference this Q&A with your [Laracasts post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/laravel-attribute-accessor-capital-letter-is-ignored) in which you detail your steps towards the solution. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

I did like this

```
protected $appends = ['image'];
public function getImageAttribute(){
      $img = null;
      $value = $this->attributes['Image'];
      if ($value) {
          if (strpos($value, 'baseurl') !== false) {
              $img = $value;
          } else {
              $img = 'prefixurl' . $value;
          }
      }
      return $img;
   }
```